# Qt, value on Spinbox are not setted correctly on first time of TreeView

Tags: qt, pyqt, treeview

I have implemented a delegate and model on a TreeView, which contains an spinbox on the column number one, but the number format is not the correct one. But, after I click the spinbox, it is setted correctly. I am using PyQt5.

Here I attached two images which explain it much better.

Value setted on a first time

[image]

The value is seen correctly after click the spinbox

[image]

Here is the code where spinbox are initialized on a first time:

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    item = index.internalPointer()
    if index.column() == 0:
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
    elif index.column() == 1:
        name = item.get_data()[0]
        data = item.get_data()[1]
        editor = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent, minimum=-9999999999, maximum=9999999999)
        # editor.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.SelectedClicked)
        editor.setObjectName(name)
        editor.setValue(data)
        editor.setStyleSheet("""
            border-radius: 0px;
        """)
        editor.installEventFilter(self)
    else:
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)

    return editor
```

I think that I missed a comitData somewhere, but I don't know where is the better place to emit it, or if it is the correct way to do that.

Thanks you,

Marcel

Comment: Put your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Now the code is attached. Sorry.

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved.

It was not in the delegate, and it has not got any relationship about QSpinBox, but the model and str format.

On QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole role on function data, I did the correct conversion, as I show on the following code:

```
def data(self, in_index, role):
    if not in_index.isValid():
        return QVariant()
    node = in_index.internalPointer()
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        if node.data(in_index.column()) is None:
            return ''
        if in_index.column() == 1:
            return str(float(node.data(in_index.column())))
        return str(node.data(in_index.column()))
```

Thanks you all.

Regards,

Marcel